# finding new line characters in a text file

Tags: python, file, newline

I have an assignment that involves creating a tail to find the last `K` lines in a file. We have been given a buffer to use for this. For now, I'm trying to write small things and search for `"\n"` characters within a file. I am running into a few problems. In `python` my code spits back **6** and in `python3` its a **0**.  The text file has WAY more than this though. Can someone please tell me why this isn't working as I would like?

```
def new():
    try:
        f = open("test.txt", "r")
        count = 0
        for i in f:
            if i == "\n":
                count = count + 1
        return count
        f.close()
    except(FileNotFoundError):
        print("No file")
```

What I would like to do is use seek to go backwards in the file and every so often search for the new line characters but this doesn't even seem to work for me.

Comment: `for i in f` iterates over lines in a file, not characters.

Comment: @Gator_Python Thank you. I thought that a for loop would iterate over each character in a file. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for i in f:` isn't doing what you think it is. The default iterator for a file gives you `lines`, not `characters`. So you're saying "Does the entire line equal just a return?"

Try instead doing `if i[-1] == "\n":` as this says "Is the last character in the line a newline?"

You might notice that this is trivially true, as each "line" is ended by a newline, so simply counting the lines is sufficient.

---

If you want to iterate through the individual characters, I would do:

```
for line in file:
    for char in line:
        dostuff()
```

Naming the variables what you think they are will also help to troubleshoot if they end up not being what you thought.

---

Example on [repl.it](https://repl.it/Dzaf/0). The variables are named `line` and `char` just to show what they are, they could be `banana` and `henry` just as easily, although then it would be less clear what was happening. `raven` simulates a file for the purposes of this example.

Comment: Thank you. I thought when you iterated through a file it would do each character within that file. The -1 index worked like a charm. Is there such a way to iterate through each character or would you have to do something like open(<file>, "rb") to read bits?

Comment: @DirtyDaver I updated it to include how I would scan a file for characters.

Comment: so "char" is built into the language and that would allow me to iterate 1 character at a time?

Comment: @DirtyDaver No, I named it `char` because that's what it represents. `line` is a string and in python if you do `for george in string` every loop `george` will have a single character.

It's just how the `for x in y` works for files and strings.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler approach would be to

- use Python's built-in ability to split a file into a list of lines
- create your tail from the last K elements of that list

If keeping the whole file in an array is a problem, you could instead read the file line-by-line, but only retain the last K lines read, so that when you reach the end of the file, you have the tail you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify the logic and use a Python built-in?

```
def new(): # not a good function name!
    try:
        with open('data1.txt') as f:
            return f.read().count('\n')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print ("No file")
```

Comment: Assignments generally require you to do it yourself -> if gave back a single-line list comprehension they would probably (rightly) assume he didn't write it himself, even though that would be my default method.

Comment: @TemporalWolf is correct we can only use what we've been taught even if we know more than that. I do like this method though and will keep this in mind. Thank you for the response. I only wrote the function new() just because I was trying to test this out before I actually add it to my code and give it a functino name like GetCharacters() or something to that.